# Нужно заменить результат работы кода с if другим результатом

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, консоль

Вопрос, полагаю, очень глупый, но уже два часа пытаюсь найти на него ответ. Я в этом деле новичок, поэтому найти ошибку в своём коде не получается.
Весь код выглядит так:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ")[0] !== null)
    if(document.querySelectorAll("img.dev-content-normal")[1] == null)
        document.querySelectorAll("img.dev-content-normal")[0].src; else document.querySelectorAll("img.dev-content-normal")[1].src;
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ")[1].href == null)
        document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ")[0].href;    else document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ")[1].href;
```

Суть в том, что мне необходимо к результату, который выводит этот код

```
if(document.querySelectorAll("img.dev-content-normal")[0].src;  else document.querySelectorAll("img.dev-content-normal")[1].src;
```

приравнять значение результата этого кода 
(в первом выводится ссылка картинки с низким разрешением, во втором с высоким, мне нужно первую ссылку заменить второй; без if для поиска ссылки не обойтись)

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ")[1].href == null)
    document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ")[0].href;    else document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ")[1].href;
```

По отдельности всё работает, но при попытке поставить между первым и вторым кодом = приводят к:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Ппопытки оформлять код отдельно, как `var test1 = код1` приводят к:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Честно говоря, даже не знаю, как сформулировать лучше свой вопрос, поэтому прошу прощение за скорей всего неправильное оглавление вопроса и возможные лишние теги.

Comment: Для начала — **НИКОГДА НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ `if` БЕЗ ФИГУРНЫХ СКОБОК!!1**

Answer (score 0):

Ох мой мозг.. Но я попытаюсь.

```
const imgNormal = document.querySelectorAll("img.dev-content-normal");
const downloadButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download ");
const href = downloadButtons[(downloadButtons[1].href == null) ? 0 : 1].href;
if(downloadButtons[0] !== null){
    imgNormal[(imgNormal[1] == null) ? 0 : 1].src = href;
}
```

Comment: Не помогло. Посижу, попытаюсь сократить размер своей писанины и выложить её упрощённой, может тогда она будет меньше давить на мозги.